# Ciclo while en JS no se repite según condición dada

Tags: javascript, condiciones, bucles, while

¿Por qué al seleccionar un número que sea mayor a 3 o menor a 0, en vez de repetirse el while, manda directo al último else?

El error que surge es que en la instrucción `while(entrada >= 4 && entrada <= -1)` al seleccionar un número que sea mayor a 3 o menor a 0, en vez de repetirse el while, manda directo al else del final.

El que dice ERROR, vuelva a intentarlo utilizando únicamente si o no. Y no entiendo por qué va directo al else luego de que se esté ejecutando la primera opción del if, pues lo que busco es validar de una manera correcta que cuando el usuario no seleccione un número válido pueda volver a elegir otro.

```js
let nombre;

let entrada2;

class Usuarios {
  constructor(id, nombre) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }
}

const usuario0 = new Usuarios(0, "Alex Argento");
const usuario1 = new Usuarios(1, "Bruno Días");
const usuario2 = new Usuarios(2, "Cosme Fulanito");
const usuario3 = new Usuarios(3, "Juan Pérez");

class Productos {
  constructor(idProducto, nombreProducto, precio) {
    this.idProducto = idProducto;
    this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
    this.precio = precio;
  }

  sumarIva() {
    this.precio = this.precio * 1.21;
    return this.precio;
  }

  descuentoParaUsuarios() {
    this.precio = this.precio - 2000;
    return this.precio;
  }

}

const producto0 = new Productos(0, "Escudo del Capitán América", 5000);
const producto1 = new Productos(1, "Disfraz de Superman", 8000);
const producto2 = new Productos(2, "Disfraz de Ironman", 30000);
const producto3 = new Productos(3, "Disfraz de la Mujer Maravilla", 4000);

//Estructura producto 0.
let precioOriginalProducto0 = producto0.precio;
let producto0PrecioConIva = producto0.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto0);
let producto0ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto0.descuentoParaUsuarios();

//Estructura producto 1.
let precioOriginalProducto1 = producto1.precio;
let producto1PrecioConIva = producto1.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto1);
let producto1ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto1.descuentoParaUsuarios();

//Estructura producto 2.
let precioOriginalProducto2 = producto2.precio;
let producto2PrecioConIva = producto2.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto2);
let producto2ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto2.descuentoParaUsuarios();

//Estructura producto 3.
let precioOriginalProducto3 = producto3.precio;
let producto3PrecioConIva = producto3.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto3);
let producto3ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto3.descuentoParaUsuarios();

nombre = prompt("Por favor, ingrese su nombre de usuario");

function saludarUsuario() {
  alert("Hola." + nombre + "\n Bienvenido a MEM Cosplay");
}

while (nombre == "") {
  alert("Lo siento, debe ingresar un nombre de usuario para continuar.");
  nombre = prompt("Por favor, ingrese su nombre de usuario");
}

saludarUsuario();

let entrada;

entrada = prompt("Contamos con una amplia variedad de productos ¿Le gustaría conocer nuestros artículos junto con\n los precios y descuentos de usuario? ");

if (entrada == "si" || entrada == "SI" || entrada == "sí" || entrada == "SÍ") {
  alert("Entonces, continuemos.\n En este momento contamos con los siguientes productos:\n " + producto0.nombreProducto + " ID: " + producto0.idProducto + ".\n" + producto1.nombreProducto + " ID: " + producto1.idProducto + ".\n" + producto2.nombreProducto + " ID: " + producto2.idProducto + ".\n" + producto3.nombreProducto + " ID: " + producto3.idProducto + "\n Para saber el precio de algún producto coloque el número de ID del mismo.");

  entrada = parseInt(prompt("¿Cual es el ID del artículo que le interesa?"));

  while (entrada >= 4 && entrada <= -1) {
    alert("Lo siento, has elegido un número de ID no válido. Por favor, vuelve a intentarlo.");
    entrada = parseInt(prompt("¿Cual es el ID del artículo que le interesa?"));
  }

  switch (entrada) {
    case 0:
      alert("El precio del producto: " + producto0.nombreProducto + " es de " + precioOriginalProducto0 + ".\n  El precio con Iva incluido es de: " + producto0PrecioConIva + ".\n Y con el descuento de usuarios quedaría en: " + producto0ConDescuentoDeUsuario);
      break;

    case 1:
      alert("El precio del producto: " + producto1.nombreProducto + " es de " + precioOriginalProducto1 + ".\n  El precio con Iva incluido es de: " + producto1PrecioConIva + ".\n Y con el descuento de usuarios quedaría en: " + producto1ConDescuentoDeUsuario);
      break;

    case 2:
      alert("El precio del producto: " + producto2.nombreProducto + " es de " + precioOriginalProducto2 + ".\n  El precio con Iva incluido es de: " + producto2PrecioConIva + ".\n Y con el descuento de usuarios quedaría en: " + producto2ConDescuentoDeUsuario);
      break;

    case 3:
      alert("El precio del producto: " + producto3.nombreProducto + " es de " + precioOriginalProducto3 + ".\n  El precio con Iva incluido es de: " + producto3PrecioConIva + ".\n Y con el descuento de usuarios quedaría en: " + producto3ConDescuentoDeUsuario);
      break;

    default:
      alert("ERROR: vuelva a entrar más tarde.");
  }

} else if (entrada == "no" || entrada == "NO") {
  alert("No hay problema, regresa cuando quieras.");

} else {
  alert("ERROR: vuelva a intentarlo utilizando únicamente las respuesta SI o NO.");

}
```

Comment: Por que estás haciendo mal la comparativa. `entrada` jamas podría cumplir AMBAS condiciones. Debes usar OR segun entiendo lo que quieres lograr... ""si el numero es mayor a 3 O menor a 0"".. Nunca dijiste Y...

Comment: `entrada >= 4 && entrada <= -1` ... entrada = 5 .... condicion 1 cumplida pero condicion 2 no cumplida... no entra al while...

Comment: `entrada >= 4 || entrada <= -1` ... entrada = 5 .... condicion 1 cumplida pero condicion 2 no cumplida... si entra al while, por que solo necesita cumplir una codicion.